# Driving a Peltier element with PWM

Tags: pwm, inductor, peltier

I'm trying to drive a Peltier element using the VNH2SP30 motor driver, switching at the Arduino's PWM frequency of ~970 Hz (which is extremely low, but I'm planning on increasing the driving frequency to 15 kHz).

For now, with no experience on LC low pass filters, I'm struggling to filter the power delivered to the Peltier element.

I'm using a combination of 5 mH ferrite core coil with a bulky 4700 µF capacitor, which is showing a relatively smooth output waveform on the scope.  Unfortunately, my inductor is getting really hot, so that I can't keep my finger on it.
PWM voltage : 12v
Duty cycle : 70~90%
Inductor current rating 2.5 amps
Inductor DCR: 73mOhm
Cap ESR : 0.5 Ohm
Max ripple level :10%
Peltier driven at 2 amps max
Peltier specs: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjagdz5gZDyAhV1CmMBHYotDasQFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw0pXUw93x3BX9LqFe4th0vf

- What is going on in the filter?
- Why is the inductor heating up that much?
- Is there any way to improve the filter?
  [image]

Comment: Few questions you should clarify: If you use PWM, why do you have an LC filter there to begin with, why not simply use PWM as PWM without LC filter? Since you have an inductor, is it rated for the current required by the peltier element? Because if you don't know if it can handle the current, why did you decide to use it? You should maybe post schematics what you have connected and how.

Comment: @Justme Driving Peltier elements with unfiltered PWM is a bad idea. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua979a/slua979a.pdf?ts=1599500951934

Comment: @JonathanS. Why not ask the OP why they think using pwm is a good idea.

Comment: 1) why would you need to use PWM? The response time of a Peltier element is so large (it cannot heat/cool instantly) that switching on/off at a rate of once per second (1 Hz) will be more than sufficient. But feel free to **prove me wrong** and show that you do need PWM and filtering. 2) Even if you use PWM, you don't need filtering, the Peltier element **doesn't care** as it is too slow to "notice" the 970 Hz anyway. Again feel free to prove me wrong. ...

Comment: ...3) what I say in 1) also means that going to 15 kHz is pointless, it will only give you more losses. 4) Filtering isn't about using large (5 mH, 4700uF) components but using **the right** components.

Comment: I dont want to concern myself too much with why pwm is less efficient than constant current drive, but here's a performance comparison by TI on driving peltiers with CC vs PWM you may wanna have a look at graphs there https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slua979&ved=2ahUKEwjRjP6m6I_yAhV98OAKHa_zAeUQFjAQegQIFhAC&usg=AOvVaw3wOFnqAkAzO-GVhhUKWWOs

Comment: What's the full spec on that inductor? Not just its inductance, but rated current, saturation current, ferrite material etc?

Comment: *I dont want to concern myself too much with why pwm is less efficient than constant current drive* No one here is discussing constant current drive. And PWM is more efficient BTW. You should concern yourself more to gain **understanding**. There's an example in that TI article, note how they're basically making a buck converter and note the values of the inductor and capacitor. Those are part of the buck converter. But again, the article is irrelevant and you still don't explain why you need PWM with filtering. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: SMDRH104220N, thats an inductor i tried, still got hot, 33uH with 4700uF cap, cut off freq ~ 400hz, inductor rated for 2.5 Amps, peltier current 1.8 amps, DCR 73m-Ohm.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, check TI's CC test circuit, its basically what im doing, the chip they are using is switching at 20kHz (hence the low filter components values), still they had to filter the output to the peltier to minimize current ripple. Thats basically what im doing, using a switching motor driver to control current to the peltier based on other sensors input by varying the duty cycle to the motor driver, only at very low frequency (hence the large inductor value to manage a cut off frequency as far as possible from my driving frequency on the low side of the scale).

Comment: *check TI's CC test circuit, its basically what im doing* Sure, to a beginner, it looks the same **but there are significant differences**. The TPS54201 is a proper **buck converter**, it uses feedback to control its output voltage. Do you use voltage feedback? Again: note the significant difference in component values. All those differences makes one circuit work well and the other not so well. The devil is in the details, similar circuit but giving completely different performance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, the vnh2sp30 has a current sense pin with 0.30v/A, i feed that into the microprocessor which adjusts the duty cycle accordingly. the TPS54201 ultimate purpose is to provide constant current by adjusting the output voltage, how is this different from what im doing with code ?

Comment: YOu need to understand impedances on each component to understand what's wrong

Comment: Show a schematic in question of ALL  values used, rather than ramble in comments , pls

Comment: the difference in component values is due to the fact that the TPS54201 is switching at 20kHz while my vnh2sp30 is switching at 970Hz, yet its capable of doing 20kHz, and good thermal performance at my desired current level, the main question is why my inductor gets hot, the values because its about attenuation and cutoff frequency, my values are ok for the driving pwm frequency im using, it actually worked and did filter the output to a smoother DC with 400mVpp ripple which is about 5%, not bad.

Comment: Missing V ,f,  duty cycle and desired ripple %

Comment: Driving Pwm V = 12v .. Duty cycle : variable between 70~90%

Comment: update question please with ALL data

Comment: including Peltier link specs and DCR, ESR or D.F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time constant in coils L/R is relative constant for a given design sizing, where R is the coil DC resistance ( DCR in spec ).

But Inductor impedance reduces with lower f.  So when you choose a lower L with lower loss ,DCR you have to raise fsw to obtain the same impedance ratio.

Then knowing the minimum R of the Peltier device and Xc cap impedance and XL choke impedance you choose the parts for low ripple and low Q which is a tradeoff.

Losses in Peltier devices increase with ripple voltage, so find good specs for optimal tradeoff on efficiency and ripple voltage would be a good start.

You have the wrong filter impedance causing massive circulating currents in the LC part.
25% of the power at 500Hz is dissipated in DCR loss.

[image]
If driven at the resonant frequency near 500 Hz the current increases x ~30 times or 28 dB around LC and not into load.

Since I guessed at your Peltier device with no specs, this is all I can say for now until your revise your question with all values of **V, PWM f , duty cycle, L,DCR, C, ESR, and Peltier specs**

using 8V 2.4A [image]  ~ 3 Ohms while LC at 500 Hz is 0.3 Ohms

When you add DCR to L and ESR to C all the energy is dissipated in these parts, so a precise filter spec needs all parameters to choose best Buck converter for a 2 to 3 ohm load

Assuming L [image]

### Solution  **(Change L to much lower DCR)**

[image]

- based on new info  for Peltier at 26 , 50 'C on hot side.

**Lessons learned:** Always be conservative on L current limit and choose one greater than max.   I chose C because I know that low ESR caps are ~ 10us so from R=T/C,  220 uF  ,you can find low DCR caps = 10 us/220 uF = < 50 mohm and reducing L by 5 in same form factor also reduces winding loss by 5.

```
  Imax (Amps)    6.4        6.4
  Vmax (Volts)  14.4       16.4 
  Resistance (Ohms)  1.98   2.30
  Power  (Watts)  92.2     105.0
```

**Root Cause design fault: Inductor DCR 73 mOhms @ 6.4A exceeds spec of 2.4A ,max** as Pd= 3W will get too hot you need Pd < 0.5W so DCR must be 0.5/3 * 73m= 12mohm  which results in lower L and thus higher f needed or more ripple  . Cap must also have ESR < 5 mOhm as they are less heat conductive.

This however has very high Q at 1kHz so startup will amplify losses 10x in 50 ms to 5 watts or so.

Thus C must also be reduced then ESR increases so losses on here are critical.

**Consider required f for ripple at 220 uF 50 mOhm low ESR. I suggest 20 kHz min. Let's see the Q next based on step response from 70 to 90% at 20kHz.**

[image]

**Conclusion**

- **Looks good and Pd in L is < 0.5W ripple < 3mVpp**

But you decide on your specs if it looks good.

Comment: Stewart, you are captioning my pain, what you said is exactly what i need yet dont know how to do.

Comment: Do you know formulae for reactive impedances?  Search for RLC nomograph as well.  Consider reduce L /10 and reduce C/10 and raise f x 10 or more

Comment: Thank you Tony, I know where to look now

Answer (score 1):

The problem with filter designs is knowing ALL the impedances of every part and power loss ratings. Then a simulation of the filter demonstrates the difference.  The effects of R loss is linear as  a ratio of your output power in series.  Thus for a 100 W load and a series choke loss of 0.5 W the DCR must also be the same Ratio. e.g. for load = 2 Ohms, 0.5Wloss/100Wload * 2 ohm load = 10 mohms DCR. But as number of turns reduces DCR , so too is L reduced so ripple increases for same f.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**
[image]

[image: AFTER]

Step response, PD and ripple shown

Answer (score 0):

First on why your inductor is heating up.  What happens when your cap is charged and the pwm in is at low?  Inductor behaves (almost) like a resistor discharging the cap into your pwm.  probably not desired.  Did you mean to add a diode between inductor and cap to prevent this or maybe to use a resistor to control the dissipation?  I'm guessing the D1 is there to protect that pwm from having current pulled by the inductor through.  D1 doesn't help in this scenario where current is being pushed by the cap instead (which will lead to being pushed by the inductor when the cap lacks charge to push).

When attempting something like this, start simple and work up.  As some comments allude, you really don't need fancy filtering for a peltier if you have control over the pwm.  A thermal mass itself acts as a low pass filter.  Start with a power supply (rated to peltier voltage and over double the peltier current), programmable pwm source, a mosfet (your motor driver works), a high wattage resistor (to limit current through the peltier), and the peltier+heat sink.  That should make for a decent learning peltier control setup.

Once you get the feel of that system work on replacing that resistor with a more efficient current limiting method.